# Why is DistinctSort followed by TopNSort in my query plan?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, azure-sql-database, sorting

I have the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobItems] (
    [ItemId]            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ItemState]         INT              NOT NULL,
    [ItemCreationTime]  DATETIME         NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
    [ItemPriority]      TINYINT          NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
    [ItemRefreshTime]   DATETIME         NULL,
    -- lots of other columns
    CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_GUID_HERE] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ItemId] ASC)
);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [JobItemsIndex]
    ON [dbo].[JobItems]([ItemId] ASC);

CREATE INDEX [GetTaskToProcessIndex]
    ON [dbo].[JobItems]([ItemState], [ItemPriority], [ItemCreationTime])
```

and the following query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) ItemId FROM JobItems
WHERE ItemState = 5 OR
   ( ( ItemState = 11 ) AND ( DATEDIFF( SECOND, ItemRefreshTime, GETUTCDATE() ) > 14 ) )
ORDER BY ItemPriority ASC, ItemCreationTime ASC
```

I run this query and inspect the actual execution plan and here's what's going on:

1. Index seek is done to retrieve items with `ItemState=5`.
2. Index seek is done to retrieve items with `ItemState=11` and then for each row a separate seek is done to retrieve `ItemRefreshTime` and the results of two seeks are filtered using nested loops.
3. Sets from 1 and 2 containing `ItemId`, `ItemCreationTime` and `ItemPriority` are concatenated and then...
4. Magical `DistinctSort` happens with `ORDER BY ItemId ASC` and finally
5. `TopNSort` happens with `ORDER BY ItemPriority ASC, ItemCreationTime ASC`

`TopNSort` and `DistinctSort` take something like 32 percent each so I'd be happy to get rid of `DistinctSort` - I don't even understand its purpose.

What's this magical `TopNSort` which useful `DistinctSort` and why is it there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce the plan that you describe on SQL Server 2012 (on prem) by running the DDL in your question and then fiddling the stats so SQL Server thinks that the table is much larger than reality.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[JobItems] WITH ROWCOUNT = 10000000, pagecount = 10000000
```

And then running the query with `OPTION (MAXDOP 1, CONCAT UNION, ORDER GROUP)`.

[image]

This is an [index union plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/index-union). The concatenation operator implements `UNION ALL`. The Distinct Sort changes the semantics to a `UNION` operation to prevent the same row being returned multiple times. (In the event the table had no index key to act as a unique row identifier the physical rid would have been used here to avoid incorrectly de-duping different rows that happen to have the same column values)

An example of where this might be needed is in the query below. (note the two parameters are set to the same value so an index union plan there would seek the same rows twice)

```
DECLARE @ItemState1   INT = 5
        , @ItemState2 INT = 5

SELECT ItemId
FROM   JobItems
WHERE  ItemState = @ItemState1
        OR ( ( ItemState = @ItemState2 )
             AND ( DATEDIFF(SECOND, ItemRefreshTime, GETUTCDATE()) > 14 ) )
```

The Top N Sort then re-sorts the data to implement the `TOP 1`.

In your case the Distinct Sort is logically not required for multiple reasons. The `ItemState = 5` and `ItemState = 11` branches are mutually exclusive (and this could be determined at compile time) and additionally the `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY ItemPriority ASC, ItemCreationTime ASC` semantics wouldn't be affected even if there were erroneous duplicates.

An alternative way of writing the query (that gives a better plan using the indexes to avoid any sorts at all) is

```
SELECT TOP(1) ItemId
FROM   (SELECT ItemId,
               ItemPriority,
               ItemCreationTime
        FROM   JobItems
        WHERE  ItemState = 5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ItemId,
               ItemPriority,
               ItemCreationTime
        FROM   JobItems
        WHERE  ( ( ItemState = 11 )
                 AND ( DATEDIFF(SECOND, ItemRefreshTime, GETUTCDATE()) > 14 ) )) T
ORDER  BY ItemPriority ASC,
          ItemCreationTime ASC
```

[image]

You could consider adding `ItemRefreshTime` as an included column to the index to avoid the key lookup if in practice quite a few may be required before finding a single row satisfying the residual predicate.